# Siri ShortCuts - NSUserActivity, Does not display given thumbnail image

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts

This is how I register my UserActivity.

I get the short cut and the functionality works.

However I get the app icon as thumbnail image but not the one I set,

```
func registerUserActivity(component: Component)
{
    userActivity = NSUserActivity.init(activityType: "com.company.app.openComponent")

    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        userActivity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
        userActivity.isEligibleForSearch = true
        userActivity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Open \(component.componentName ?? "recent Component")"
    }

    userActivity.title = "Open \(component.componentName ?? "recent component")"
    userActivity.userInfo = ["componentName" : component.componentName]

     let attributes = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet.init(itemContentType: kUTTypeItem as String)

    let image =   UIImage(named: "cloud_car")!
    attributes.thumbnailData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    attributes.contentDescription = "Opens \(component.componentName ?? "recent Component") "
    userActivity.contentAttributeSet = attributes
    userActivity.becomeCurrent()

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem and have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can determine, there are 2 possible issues causing this. The first is that your logic should be: `attributes.thumbnailData = image.pngData()`. If that's not it, it's an issue with caching a thumbnail for a specific `NSUserActivity`, and has been there since iOS 9. The `CoreSpotlight` framework seems to associate the icon data with the `activityType`, so if you've previously donated that `NSUserActivity` object, creating a new `NSUserActivity` object won't allow you to update the icon image, even if you haven't previously provided an icon image. The best you can do is to keep track of all the persistent identifiers internally, delete the old one, and create a brand new NSUserActivity which the user will have to treat as a new shortcut as well.

It's definitely a dumb issue, and I'd have hoped that in the 3.5 years since iOS 9 came out, Apple would have introduced a way to update an `NSUserActivity`'s thumbnail image, but I can't find any evidence that this is the case. Sorry I could give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

When an `NSUserActivity` is displayed in Shortcuts or Siri Suggestions, it always uses the app icon. There is currently no way to change this behaviour.

The thumbnail in the attribute set is only used when an item is shown in Spotlight search results. So if an activity appears in search results I've found that it will use the thumbnail there.

This behaviour is poorly documented. It's easy to read the `CoreSpotlight` docs and think that thumbnails will work the same for `NSUserActivity`, but they simply aren't supported.